# Interpolate string length into fortran format specifier

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile someone else's FORTRAN code using gfortran 4.4.6.  The original coder used something like Compaq FORTRAN.

The code in question is supposed to read a filename like 'foo.txt' and create a new file called 'foo_c.txt':

```
    file_label_end = SCAN(filename, '.') - 1
    WRITE (output_filename,5) filename
    5 FORMAT (A<file_label_end>, '_c.txt' )
```

gfortran complains about the opening angle bracket of the character specifier.  That is, rather than "A3" he has "A<(a variable with value 3)>". I cannot find any information about interpolating format widths from variables... Is this possible?  If not, what's the best way to fix this?

**Update:**

This seems to be working (compiling):

```
file_label_end = SCAN(par_filename, '.', .TRUE. ) + 1
output_filename = par_filename(1:file_label_end) // '_c.par'
```

but I later have a similar case:

```
12 FORMAT (<n-1>F10.5)
...
READ(1,12) (cat_parm (blk,j), j = 1,n-1)
```

which I attempted to fix by creating a format string:

```
write(fmt12,'(I0,A4)') n-1, 'F10.5'
!12 FORMAT (fmt12)
12 FORMAT (fmt=fmt12)
```

But the "t" in "fmt" gets flagged with an error about "Nonnegative width required in format string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `<>` in Fortran edit descriptors is non-standard, though widely implemented.  You certainly can build edit descriptors from variables, the standard way is through an internal write, something like this (omitting declarations):

```
format_string = ''
write(format_string,'(a1,i0,a6)') 'A', file_label_end,'''_c.txt''' ! WARNING I haven't tested this
```

and then

```
write(output_filename,fmt=format_string) filename
```

But in your case this is not entirely necessary.  You could try this instead

```
file_label_end = SCAN(filename, '.') - 1
WRITE (output_filename,'(a)') filename(1:file_label_end)//'_c.txt'
```

With the 'a' edit descriptor omitting a width means that all the characters in the expression will be written.  You may want to declare

```
character(len=*), allocatable :: output_filename
```

if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Very helpful.  Also, the BACK option of SCAN was useful.  But I tried applying this to another instance in the program.  I create a string variable that holds a format; when I use it ("12 FORMAT (fmt12)" or "12 FORMAT (fmt=fmt12)"), the compiler flags that line with "Nonnegative width required in format string" (it actually flags the 't' in fmt [in both cases]).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use modern fortran

```
WRITE (output_filename,'(a)') trim(filename) // '_c.txt'
```

Otherwise I would write the number in the format string using a similar internal write.